# Unable to upload an APK file to hockey app via their API

Tags: android, curl, continuous-integration, hockeyapp, teamcity-9.0

I am unable to upload an android apk to hockeyapp through the API provided by them.When i use

```
curl \ -F "status=2" \
-F "notify=1" \ 
-F "notes=Some new features and fixed bugs." \ 
-F "notes_type=0" \
-F "apk=@app-release.apk" \
-H "X-HockeyAppToken: MY_TOKEN" \https://rink.hockeyapp.net/api/2/apps/MY_APP_ID/app_versions/upload
```

i am getting an error :   **{"status":null}**

And when I try

```
 curl \ 
-F "status=2" \ 
-F "notify=1" \
-F "notes=Some new features and fixed bugs." \ 
-F "notes_type=0" \ -F "apk=@app-release.apk" \
-H "X-HockeyAppToken: MY_TOKEN" \ https://rink.hockeyapp.net/api/2/apps/upload
```

an error occurs :  **{"status":"error","message":"File not found. Please check that your file is not a directory or bundle."}**

Please give me a solution.Drag and drop is working for me.But I need it to be done through their API.I am using Team City as my CI server.

Comment: Please contact HockeyApp support at http://support.hockeyapp.net/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The parameter for the build is called "ipa" on all platforms, i.e. `-F "ipa=@app-release.apk"` would be correct.